# UWP MediaCapture initialization fails

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, voice-recording

I'm developing a WPF application where I'm recording audio data with the `Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture` class. It's working if I initialize with or without parameters:

```
var mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();
```

or I can add which microphone to use (if there are more than one):

```
var allAudioDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.AudioCapture);
DeviceInformation microphone = allAudioDevices.FirstOrDefault();

MediaCaptureInitializationSettings mediaInitSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings {
    AudioDeviceId = microphone.Id,
    StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Audio
};

await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(mediaInitSettings);
```

The problem comes when I run my app as a UWP application (with desktop bridge). As a UWP app when it calls the `InitializeAsync()` method, it always throws an exception with the following (verbose :) ) error message: `Element not found.` The `DeviceInformation` object of the microphone is found correctly, so something happens during the initialization of the `MediaCapture`.

The Microphone capability is set in the manifest file of the bridge project.

What am I doing wrong? I'm also open to use other methods to record the voice.

Comment: I tried your code, but we could not reproduce your issue, could you share [mcve] that could reproduce this issue.

Comment: In meantime I figured out that if I run the initialization on the UI thread then a windows popup appears, which asks permission from the user to access the microphone. If I give the access, the rest is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that if I run the initialization on the UI thread, it works well:

```
await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(async () => {
    await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();
});
```